# Does GAE Windows SDK for PHP include jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-app-engine

I am using Google App Engine PHP SDK for Windows v1.8.8 and would like to use jQuery for client-side validation and Ajax interaction with a server-side Cloud SQL database.  I haven't tried using it yet, but given the difficulties of client-side debugging, I thought I should ask some simple questions that I have not seen definitively answered anywhere:

**Does the Google App Engine PHP SDK support jQuery natively?**

Is there a jQuery file in the SDK that needs to be included in my scripts?

If I need to download a jQuery library, what would be a good choice?

Thank you for any information you can provide.

Answer (score 3):

All of the App Engine SDKs are completely agnostic to client-side JavaScript frameworks. Use whatever you'd like. There's no direct notion of 'native' support.

When you deploy, you're welcome to use use as a CDN (Content Distribution Network) for jQuery. See https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery for supported versions of jQuery.